# Bootstrap Custom CSS Specificity Not Overwriting Brand Image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay, so I am a beginner but I've read a decent amount on this situation. But I'm trying to put my brand image in my nav bar.

I know it will be something stupid and small. I can always overwrite the style in the HTML but I'd prefer to have it done in a custom css file.

First things first, getting the obvious out of the way. My custom CSS file is the last css declared in the head. I am able to modify other elements on the page like paragraph element colors, so I know the CSS file is linked properly. I understand specificity, at least the core concept of it.

To try to tackle the specificity issue. I first made a custom id for my  so within the tag I declared  and in my CSS file I wrote

```
#logo {
    height: 110%;
}
```

Nothing. So I tried being more specific and adding every single class declaration possible that could point to the logo file.

```
#logo .nav .navbar .navbar-inverse .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
...
}
```

again no luck. I tried just .navbar-brand and every single combination of classes. I just don't understand the hierarchy and who is taking precedence. My CSS file, if listed last in the header, with a properly Specified class declaration should overwrite any of bootstrap's code.

I know this question must get asked a lot but after hours of searching for the answer I haven't found it anywhere.

html snippet of the section

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
        <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Limit Magazine">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post html snippet, just one child above the logo container would be enough.

Comment: @blushrt I added it to the post, the only larger div is the one that opens the nav section

<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is you are specifying the height in percentage, which requires the high of the parent element to be defined. In Bootstrap 3 the parent element of `.navbar-brand` is `div.navbar-header` and it has no defined height. For that reason `height: 110%;` does not work. So you need to define the height of the logo in pixels or define it in percentage and define `div.navbar-header` height in pixels.

Comment: Thank you this does solve the problem. 


I noticed in my inspector that .navbar-brand had a set height of 50px but the whole line had a strike through it. Does that mean that the .navbar-brand's CSS rules are being ignored because of something else.

Comment: Always welcome! Please feel free to mark my answer as accepted:) This means that these CSS rules are overwritten somewhere else. It could be the same CSS file or a different one.